# Wait() method of a task bloks the Task

Tags: c#, xamarin, task

I am working in Xamarin where I have a Task that I start at the first menupage, go through several other menupages, and then want to wait for it's completion when opening an endpage. To do this I save the task in a static field when starting it:

```
    private static Task myTask;

    public static void sync(User user)
    {
        if (myTask== null || myTask.IsCompleted) {
            myTaskStarted = true;
            //Note: do not trust on the variable being filled in immediately after the start of the task. It takes a minute. Use the flag
            myTask= AsyncMyTask(user);
        }
    }
```

And then later I call a method from another page that is simply supposed to wait for myTask to finnish by calling `myTask.Wait()` after doing some checks on myTask having been started and not being null. But I see that once I call `myTask.Wait()` myTask is stuck and no longer progresses in the debugger. It's stuck. If I replace `myTask.Wait()` by `myTask.Wait(1000)` myTask is frozen for the duration of the timeout. After the timeout it continues. This is not the behaviour that is described in the documentation. Can anyone explain why the AsyncMyTask method is blocked when you call myTask.Wait() from the UI thread?

---

As requested: the AwaitMyTask method:

```
    public async static Task<Boolean> AwaitMyTask()
    {
        if(!myTaskStarted && myTask== null)
        {
            return false;
        } else
        {
            while (myTask== null)
            {
                Task.Delay(10);
            }
        }
        //Stuck on the line below
        myTask.Wait();
        myTaskStarted = false;
        return myTask.IsCompleted;
    }
```

Comment: To add to Peter's answer, see: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: There's a few missing pieces in your question, It'd be worth while seeing the method where you actually perform the wait if I'm being honest.

Comment: You are using `async` but never `await`. You can do `await myTask;` instead of `myTask.Wait();`. This will block almost the same way. If you want to await multiple tasks then you can use `await Task.WhenAll(...)`

Comment: I've tried this, it blocks the execution of myTask too.

Comment: Of course it is going to block, that what `Wait` and `await` are for. If you don't want to block current execution then remove `Wait` or `await` from your code, but this is not adivisable.

Comment: It's not the execution of AwaitMyTask blocking that I have a problem with, it's AsyncMyTask blocking along with it.

Comment: AsyncMyTask is the method that is executed in myTask, as you can see in the code, so since it blocks the 'Wait' or 'await' are also stuck forever.

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Wait` is a synchronously awaiting the task which blocks the thread. Unless you can point to a documentation stating something else, I'd say that it's expected behavior as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx

> Wait is a synchronization method that causes the calling thread to wait until the current task has completed. ...

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if multipleTasks are in the same thread, then calling task.Wait() on one task from another will suspend all those tasks. Not really what I'd expect, thank you.

Comment: As far as I've read a task is automatically started in it's own thread, so, no, I don't think that it makes sense that the task is suspended if you call task.Wait, it should only be the thread that calls the method that is suspended, not both.

Comment: @Lavandysh maybe you need to update your description because this part of your question: `If I replace myTask.Wait() by myTask.Wait(1000) myTask is frozen for the duration of the timeout.` suggests expected behavior, in maybe you got mixed up with the description of the main task and the sub task - additionally, C# doesn't say that tasks must run in a separate thread, they can (by default they even might), but don't have to. I don't know what default values in xamarin specify though.